# <nav> List with images

Tags: html, css, nav

I have a nav tag and inside is a list of sport teams. Next to the name of each team I have its logo. The list is inside a responsive page. All logos are positioned correctly on a large windows but when on smaller windows like tablets and smartphones each logo goes down as if it is the logo of the team underneath. This is the css I have for each emblem: `float:right;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:10px;` What can I do to eliminate this problem?

List code:

```
<li>
            <a href="Link to team 1 page">Team1</a>
            <img src="team logo.png link" alt="team1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" style="float:right;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:10px;">
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="team 2 page link">Team 2</a>
            <img src="team2.png link" alt="team 2" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" style="float:right;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:10px;">
        </li>
        <li>
            <a "Team 3 page link">Team 3</a>
            <img src="team3.png link" alt="team 3" height="22" width="24" class="itemImg" style="float:right;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:10px;">
        </li>
        <li>
            <a"team 4 page link">Team 4</a>
            <img src="team4.png link" alt="team4" height="18" width="20" class="itemImg" style="float:right;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:10px;">
        </li>
```

Comment: can you share code with us ?

Comment: post all the relevant code to solve this problem?

Comment: You must to share code, but I think that your problem is float property. Float is a scar. Avoid to use it for non-floating purposes. Layout is not equal to floating.

Comment: When you use `float`, your elements' width must to be smaller than parent's width. if their width greater, it will move to underneath. You should use % to decide width of elements

Comment: are u using `bootstrap`

Comment: Kindly add the code or add the image which can give us more detail for both the state (mobile and desktop).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing enough of your CSS to properly answer the question but I'm going to guess that the issue involves the width of your anchor `<a>` element. It must be set in some way that it occupies enough width of the browser that forces the image to drop down on smaller screens. To solve the issue, you can float the anchor left or make the width smaller.

If nothing else, it will show that is the issue at hand and you can go from there.